# PGAdmin gets estimated row count from where?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, rowcount

I noticed that the estimated row count isn't updated after removing some rows from the table.

[image]

So, I ran `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the table, but it didn't work either.
 Where is the place PGAdmin takes this value from? Does the ***query planner*** take the estimated row count from the same place?

Version: `PostgreSQL 9.4`

Comment: `SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'tbl_name';`

Comment: @lad2025 The planner takes the estimated row count that way?

Comment: pgadmin caches a lot of information. When in doubt: always use `refresh`.

Comment: @St.Antario The numbers of the planner and the `pg_class` table are at least equal in one of my tables (with 10^7 rows).

Answer (score 1):

If it is row count you want, why not try this :

```
SELECT count(*) as rowCount FROM table
```

Comment: No, the question is about another thing.

Comment: Try closing the PGAdmin and opening again. Worked for me when I added a new Table which didn't show in the tables' tree structure even after refreshing. But showed up when I closed and reopened PGAdmin.